# How to use template inside template using vue.js & laravel?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, vue-component, laravel-elixir

In my project using laravel elixir to mix up the JavaScript files.

In forms I have to use main Vue.js element to create forms. Also I have to use `vue-google-map` template inside parent Vue.js element but it is showing an error?

```js
window.VueGoogleMaps = require('vue2-google-maps');
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#participantLocationListApp',
});
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default card-view panel-refresh" id="participantLocationListApp">
    <template>
        <gmap-map:center="center" :zoom="1" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"> </gmap-map>
    </template>
</div>
```

Error:

[image: Vue.Element&anothe template for google-maps]

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: `<gmap-map>` - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
>
> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: `<gmap-info-window>` - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Comment: how about you show your code?

Comment: JS:`window.VueGoogleMaps = require('vue2-google-maps');
var app = new Vue({
 el: '#participantLocationListApp',}) ` HTML:`<div class="panel panel-default card-view panel-refresh" id="participantLocationListApp"><template > <gmap-map:center="center"  :zoom="1" style="width: 100%; height: 400px">
</gmap-map></template></div>`

Comment: @OshosanyaMichael

Answer (score 0):

You are just declaring the plugin. [You have to "use" it](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Using-a-Plugin), so Vue knows about it.

Also, that `<template>` makes no sense, you don't want it there.

Here's how it should be:

In the JavaScript code, activate the plugin [**through `.use()`**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Using-a-Plugin):

```js
var VueGoogleMaps = require('vue2-google-maps');

// from the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps#with-npm-recommended
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps , {
  load: {
    key: 'YOUR_API_TOKEN',
    v: '3.26',                // Google Maps API version
    // libraries: 'places',   // If you want to use places input
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#participantLocationListApp',
})
```

HTML (remove the `<template>`):

```html
<div class="panel panel-default card-view panel-refresh" id="participantLocationListApp">
    <gmap-map :center="center" :zoom="1" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></gmap-map>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. console errors cleared But map not showing `<iframe frameborder="0" src="about:blank" style="z-index: -1; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; border: none;"></iframe>`

Comment: Double check the map declaration, the API key, the version. It really should work now.

Comment: How did it go ?